# meaning of "tick off"

Tags: meaning

As per [merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tick%20off) "tick off" could mean "to make angry" or "reprimand". However, it seems to have another meaning in a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/OyPvI_NxZU8?list=PLdawRnR9ilZBWJsnzHhkzFywWmwhvqlWD&t=398).

There are 2 guys showing the IELTS speaking test, the women is role-playing the examiner and gives the following comments to the guy role-playing the candidate.

> the examiner is **ticking off**, very nice
>   linking word, very nice intonation, Oh
>   past perfect continuous ... **you're doing OK.**

What is the meaning of "tick off" there?

Comment: The sense that it is being used there is primarily BrE: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/tick-off?q=Tick+off

Comment: @ColleenV Thank you. you mean "to put a mark ...", right?

Comment: Well, it might be used figuratively there instead of literally checking a box - I hope someone who has more time than I do right now will write a proper answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

In America, this is usually called a check mark, in Britain it is usually called a tick: ✓. To tick something off (e.g. in a list) literally means to place such a mark against that item, or figuratively to name items in a list (which may be a mentally held one), as the examiner is doing.

> **to put a mark beside an item in a list to show that you have dealt
>   with it:**
>   That's one more action point that we can tick off.
>
> **to name items in a list:**
>   She ticked off six reasons for saying no.

[Tick off (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tick-sth-off?q=tick%20off)

Comment: Thank you. So, "check list" in AmE is called "tick list" in BrE, right?

Comment: Not always. A 'check list' could be a list to things to check (i.e. examine, verify, evaluate for correctness) and we have those in BrE.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the verbal phrase (*tick off*) doesn't list the sense you want, but if you look at just the verb itself, you'll see an entry for it under [**tick**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tick#h2).:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   *transitive verb*
>   **1** : to mark with a written tick : CHECK —usually used with *off*
>        // *ticked* off each item in the list
>   **2** : to mark, count, or announce by or as if by ticking beats
>        // a meter *ticking* off the cab fare

As a general rule, when looking up phrases like this, if you can't locate what you want from the entire phrase, look up the verb on its own, and then do a search for the additional word.

In this case, not finding it under *tick off*, I looked up *tick* and then searched for *off*. This let me find the entry.